# double type array use in J2ME

Tags: arrays, java-me, double

I have use Double type array, it works in Emulator but showing error in mobile, what is  the problem??

Comment: please state your problem clearly, if possible, give some code snippets that you are working on.

Comment: What handset are You using. To use floating point numbers Your handset needs to support CLDC-1.1

Answer (score 0):

make sure the handset that you have provisioned to is capable of cldc 1.1 which is needed for floating point numbers, you can change how the emulator behaves in its settings to represent a cldc 1.0 device if that is what you are building for